# Get Nuget package properties from assembly attributes (in Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2022.
In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file I have an `AssemblyVersion` attribute:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3")
```

I want to generate a NuGet package automatically on build, and I was wondering if it would be possible to specify, in the package properties dialog, to use the `AssemblyVersion` as package version, to avoid having to remember to change the version in two places each time.

Something like this (which doesn't work):

[image: Package properties]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `$(AssemblyVersion)` value is trying to reference an MSBuild property. It cannot see an `[AssemblyVersion]` attribute in your code at build time. I recommend you move the specification of the version to your project file (search for "version" in that UI, or edit your `.csproj` and set the `<Version>` property manually. In that way you only have to set the value once; the version will be set on the assembly, and used during pack operations.

Comment: If I remove the `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` attributes I actually get a dll with version `0.0.0.0` for both.

Comment: Did you also add a `<Version>` property to your project though?

Comment: Yes, I did. Can I put that in any `<PropertyGroup>` node or should it be in a specific one?

Comment: Just make sure the `<PropertyGroup>` doesn't have a `Condition` attribute. You want that property set unconditionally.

Comment: Can you include the full content of your `.csproj` file in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `AssemblyInfo` and specify the version in your csproj file (see below). `dotnet pack` then should produce both package and dll with correct version.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>

        ...

        <Version>MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH</Version>
        <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    ...

</Project>
```